# want to count and show total of employee's leaves of diffterent types on main form

Tags: dcount

hi  i have made a simple database to track employee leaves and want to show a employee leaves total of each leave type at bottom of main form. i have main table with all details then i made queries of each leave type for example L1Qurey is for admin leave L2Query is for sick leave like this i have 5 queries then i made a data entry screen to enter data for employees and i want to show total number of leaves for every leave type at the bottom of data entry screen i enter a employee id and it should update as new data is entered thanks

I don't have much vba knowledge but i tries Dcount function and some other query filtering, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.